# Struggling with conditional logic

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

EDITED QUESTIONS:

I can't seem to figure out the conditional logic for my query.

I am certain that this is simple but I have been spinning my wheels on this one for too long - it is just one of those days.

Any help is always appreciated.

CURRENT QUERY:

```
SELECT
    r.WidgetPK
    ,r.WidgetName
    ,r.WeightRateFlag                       [WeightRateFlag]
    ,r.Rate                                 [Rate]
    ,r.Breakpoint                           [Breakpoint]
    ,MAX(ISNULL(f.ShippingFee,0))           [ShippingFee]
    ,MAX(ISNULL(f.OtherFee,0))              [OtherFee]
    ,MAX(r.weight)                          [Weight]
FROM
    #Rates r
    LEFT JOIN #Fees f ON f.WidgetPK = r.WidgetPK
```

I left out the GROUP BY for simplicity.

If the WeightRateFlag has a 1 in it in ANY row for each WidgetPK then all rows with a 0 will not be returned.  If the WeightRateFlag has no rows with a 1 in it then ALL rows will be returned.

Sorry the original question wasn't clear -  searches aren't helping and I asked a coworker.  I think my problem may just be that I am asking the wrong question here and in my searches.

Comment: Please include an [mcve] (ie. input, expected output, and query you have so far) and tag your rdbms platform.

Comment: Consider using a UNION All, first query gets the ones with a 1 and the second one excludes any records where any of them have a 1

Comment: @HLGEM a UNION ALL is what got me to this point the #Rates temp table is the union of 2 other tables.  I didn't create the tables nor do I have edit abiities.  Most WidgetPKs are in the first table in the UNION and a handful are in the second BUT if they are in the second they are also in the first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
r.WidgetPK
,r.WidgetName
,r.WeightRateFlag                       [WeightRateFlag]
,r.Rate                                 [Rate]
,r.Breakpoint                           [Breakpoint]
,MAX(ISNULL(f.ShippingFee,0))           [ShippingFee]
,MAX(ISNULL(f.OtherFee,0))              [OtherFee]
,MAX(r.weight)                          [Weight]
FROM
#Rates r
LEFT JOIN #Fees f ON f.WidgetPK = r.WidgetPK
WHERE r.WeightRateFlag = 1
UNION ALL 
SELECT
r.WidgetPK
,r.WidgetName
,r.WeightRateFlag                       [WeightRateFlag]
,r.Rate                                 [Rate]
,r.Breakpoint                           [Breakpoint]
,MAX(ISNULL(f.ShippingFee,0))           [ShippingFee]
,MAX(ISNULL(f.OtherFee,0))              [OtherFee]
,MAX(r.weight)                          [Weight]
FROM
#Rates r
LEFT JOIN #Fees f ON f.WidgetPK = r.WidgetPK
WHERE r.WeightRateFlag = 0 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #rates r2  WHERE r2WeightRateFlag =1 AND r.WidgetName = r2.WidgetName)
```

Comment: +1 Thanks this is working - I may need to fine tune it because it is taking a performance hit but this is on the right track.

Comment: Most likely you can do something similar in how you create #rates instead. Or alternatively temp tables can be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

A bit convoluted-looking, but CTEs can be extremely helpful. Plus they should work pretty well with the optimizer. Modify for the columns you need.

```
/* TEST DATA SETUP */
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#t1') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
     DROP TABLE #t1
END
CREATE TABLE #t1 (WidgetPK int, col1 varchar(19), WeightRateFlag bit, ShippingFee money, OtherFee money, [Weight] int);
INSERT INTO #t1 (WidgetPK, col1, WeightRateFlag, ShippingFee, OtherFee, [Weight])
VALUES
      (1, 'showme1', 1, 9, 1, 1)
    , (1, 'noshow2', 0, 2, 9, 2)
    , (1, 'noshow3', 0, 1, 2, 9)
    , (2, 'showme1', 1, 9, 9, 9)
    , (3, 'showme1', 0, 1, 9, 1)
    , (3, 'showme2', 0, 9, 9, 9)
    , (3, 'showme3', 0, 9, 1, 9)
;

/* QUERY STARTS HERE */
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT x1.* 
    FROM (
        SELECT #t1.WidgetPK, #t1.col1, #t1.WeightRateFlag, #t1.ShippingFee, #t1.OtherFee, #t1.[Weight]
            , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY #t1.WidgetPK ORDER BY #t1.WeightRateFlag DESC) AS rn
        FROM #t1
    ) x1 WHERE x1.rn = 1

)
, cte2 AS (
    SELECT cte1.WidgetPK
        , MAX(cte1.ShippingFee) AS ShippingFee
        , MAX(cte1.OtherFee) AS OtherFee
        , MAX(cte1.[Weight]) AS [Weight]
    FROM cte1
    GROUP BY cte1.WidgetPK
)
SELECT cte1.WidgetPK, cte1.col1, cte1.WeightRateFlag, cte2.ShippingFee, cte2.OtherFee, cte2.[Weight]
FROM cte1
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte2 ON cte1.WidgetPK = cte2.WidgetPK
;
```